# Facebook Authentication + Load balancer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3

So there is only one other thread on here that I've found with this issue in mind, unfortunately it has 1 answer with 0 up-votes.

My issue is the site I'm currently maintaining uses the omniauth gem to authentication new and existing users through the facebook API. When we switched over to using two servers (with identical rails apps using the same database) it broke the facebook logins. Obviously my theory is that app01 tried to use the facebook auth to sign in user1 but the response from facebook may have went through the load balancer to app02?

If you have any experience with this issue then please dont hesitate to explain how you solved it.

If i discover the answer I will be sure to post my findings.

Comment: Is your load balancing noticeable from the “outside”, i.e. a redirect to another address, or is it “transparent”?

Comment: The load balancer is transparent