# Facebook authentication callback to wrong server with AWS ELB elastic load balancer

Tags: facebook, authentication, amazon-web-services, callback

Final Edit/Conclusion:

For the specific use case documented in section "context" below, the sticky sessions won't help.  This points out the need for establishing a session before generating the authentication request.  By setting up a page with a link to the route, the problem didn't reproduce.

Issue:

For multiple webservers under an AWS ELB elastic load balancer, a Facebook authentication callback may direct to a server other than issued the authentication request.

We're using node.js with passport for authentication.

Context:

Users were given a specific route (something like ourwebsite.com/dofbstuff ) and the handler for that route does a passport authenticate first thing:

```xx
    app.get( '/dofbstuff',
        passport.authenticate( 'facebook', {    
                            scope: [ 'email', <snip> 'publish_actions' ],
                            callbackURL:config.facebook.fbstuffCallback
                         } )
```

In this use case, the app works perfectly for one app server, but hangs with multiple servers.

Question:

What's the easiest way to solve this?

Potential solutions:

1. On the app server, replace:

```xx
passport.use( new FacebookStrategy(...),function(accessToken){ etc. } )
```

with

```xx
  callTheAuthenticationServer( function(accessToken){ etc. } )
```

1. (continued) and have the authentication server issue the auth request to Facebook (it resides on it's own DNS address for the call back) and issues a response to the app server.  Then how will the req be forwarded to the authentication server to generate the Facebook login dialog on the client (user's browser)?
2. Have the app server find out what port it's being forwarded from on the NAT.  The ELB would need to accept a Facebook callback with that port in the URL (i.e. myserver.com/fbauthcallbackroute:portnumber ).
3. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-iam-now-supports-amazon-facebook-and-google-identity-federation/ claims "A similar flow can also be enabled for Facebook or Google identities by integrating their SDKs with your app and simply creating an additional role."  I don't know if this means you can use Identity Federation as a means to obtaining a Facebook token.  If so, where is this process documented?

Other notes:

I found this issue posted already here (in a ruby rails environment):
[Facebook Authentication + Load balancer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11527175/facebook-authentication-load-balancer)

I have also logged a bug for passport-facebook on github here:
https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook/issues/104

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS ELBs have "sticky sessions", which will keep a particular user (via a cookie) on the same instance for the duration of their browsing session.

Another option is setting up a shared session store (AWS ElastiCache is perfect for this) so all servers store sessions in the same data store. That way, the user's session data isn't specific to an individual backend server.

Comment: sorry - but I am not aware of Facebook creating such a cookie for it's callback.  Have you actually implemented what you are talking about?

Comment: @javabrain Yes, I have implemented this, and it has nothing to do with Facebook's side of things. Sticky sessions is a configuration option in the AWS Console for the ELB. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/US_StickySessions.html

Comment: The callback for auth comes from the Facebook side.  When you tell facebook "go to this callback URL" - the ELB has no idea what context Facebook is issuing this get (or post) at that callback URL for.

No?

Comment: The ELB sets a cookie on the user's browser. That cookie tells the ELB on subsequent visits which server you were on previously, and sends your second request to the same one. **I linked you to the docs.** Your cluster acts as a single-server cluster for the individual user's purposes.

Comment: Hence a sticky session has to do with a cookie from a user client browser to an app server - maintaining traffic to the same server for that session.  But when Facebook calls the callback URL, any other app server might get that call.  I don't see how sticky sessions solves this problem.  I don't even see how an incoming Facebook callback route could be associated with a specific session via elasticache (there could be several sessions concurrently so which callback does it go to)?

Comment: Facebook doesn't make an HTTP request to your server. They redirect your user's browser to the callback URL. They'll have all their cookies with them.

Comment: Okay - if that's true then this is starting to look like a different issue (i.e. specific to how we've written our app).  I'm pretty sure we have sticky sessions enabled.

Thanks.

Comment: I just added a Context section to the OP specifically under what conditions we see the failure.  I'll try making this route accessible from inside a loaded page.  My hypothesis is that users going directly to the route haven't established any cookie (just a wild theory), and expecting if they've loaded a page and go to the same route it will work find on multiple servers.